# How to get active user's email in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a company website which has different permissions for different users. The authentication works by comparing the current users google login email to the ones on a google sheet, and that way gets the correct permissions for the website. The program works well, but can't detect the email from an user who isn't the editor of the script. I understand this is to prevent websites collecting email adresses, but is there a way to ask the user's permission to view his/hers login email adress name in order to get the correct permissions?
The code looks like this:

```
  var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  var email = user.getEmail();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('link to the google sheet I use').getActiveSheet();
...
//In a loop to go through sheet:

  if(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() === email && email !== ""){
    //Continue...
  }
```

If i try this with other users, the email is blank. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Is the web app set to "execute the app as user accessing the web app"?

Comment: It was executed only on the devloper user, now I changed it to "User accessing the web app" and now it's working as intended. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apps Script Web App documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions):

> The permissions for a web app differ depending how you choose to execute the app:
>
> **Execute the app as me** — In this case, the script always executes as you, the owner of the script, no matter who accesses the web app.
>
> **Execute the app as user accessing the web app** — In this case, the script runs under the identity of the active user using the web app. This permission approach causes the web app to show the email of the script owner when the user authorizes access.

Therefore, *in order to retrieve the email of the current user* you will have to change the permission to **Execute the app as user accessing the web app**.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).